# incorrect output for set input

Tags: java

So I almost have this code correct but it's not giving me the correct output for some reason and I can't figure out why. This is what I have:

```
package edu.ilsu;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * @author Nick
 */
public class Seconds {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hours, minutes, number_of_seconds, seconds;
        System.out.print("50391");
        number_of_seconds = in.nextInt();
        hours=number_of_seconds-number_of_seconds%3600;
        seconds=number_of_seconds%60;
        minutes=(number_of_seconds-hours-seconds)/60;
        hours=hours/3600;
        System.out.println("hours: " + hours);
        System.out.println("minutes: " + minutes);
        System.out.println("seconds: " + seconds);

    }

}
```

That is what I have so far but I need the output to be

```
Enter number of seconds: 50391
Hours: 13
Minutes: 59
Seconds 51
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [How to be a Programmers; Learn to Debug](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2790282).  That said, debugging is specifically mentioned as off topic in the [help/on-topic].  You may also find a [Java debugging with eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) tutorial helpful.

Comment: one good thing to try is to check your math with a calculator if its giving bad results.

Comment: I upvoted Question because it clearly states in the Help Ask Section "1.Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." And it seems you have a clear question right here

Comment: You said "I need the output to be etc etc etc" I run the code and the numbers are what you wanted the output to be. Or are you talking about the Strings of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Go through each step by hand (or even use System.out.printlns/logging at each step. I am not ashamed to say I do this a decade+ after learning coding)

```
hours = number_of_seconds - number_of_seconds%3600;
```

Evaluates to:

```
46800 = 50391 - 3591
```

The intended logic would in fact be

```
//pseudocode, may have to floor or whatnot, but this should get you in right direction
hours = number_of_seconds/3600;
number_of_seconds -= hours*3600;
```